# SoapUI REST service - Saved response is unreadable

Tags: rest, soapui

I am new to SOAPUI. I am using dump file property to save response json from a REST request. In SOAPUI interface, the json/ and xml is readable. But the response saved in dump file is completely unreadable characters. I am giving .json extension in dump file property.

Please help.

Thanks
Meenakshi

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Meenakshi, what version of the SoapUI are you using?

Comment: Its SoapUI 5.3.0.

Comment: Hi ImaginaryHuman072889, I am asking as why the response stored in the dump file is unreadable.